# Cakephp - Delete entry that isn't exist in new POST data

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm making something like Online Restaurant Menu where the admin can edit it.

The database looks like this:

```
CATEGORIES
id   |  name
1    | Western Food

FOODS
id   | category_id | name
1    |      1      | Tenderloin
2    |      1      | Fish Chips
```

After the admin edit a menu, it reads all the inputs and post them as AJAX request. The data (simplified) looks like this:

```
data: [
    {Category: {id: 1, name:'Western Food'} },
    {Food: [
        {id: 1, category_id: 1, name: 'Tenderloin'}, //Have ID = edit old entry
        {category_id: 1, name: 'Burger'}, //Don't have ID = create new entry
    ]}
]
```

The `saveAll()` function in CakePHP did a great job at automatically detect whether it's Editing or Creating new entry based on the existence of `id` column in the data.

As you can see above, at first we have 2 foods in table. But the new POST data doesn't contain food with ID=2, so it means that food is deleted. **How do I delete that**?

Is there built-in function to **detect which entry aren't modified**?

Sorry, for the long question. Please ask for clarification if it confuses you.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by simply deleting all old entries before saving the new one.

It may not be the best practice, but... oh well.

Comment: There isn't a built-in function for that, so deleting and saving is correct, you should accept your own answer. As a sidenote, this "deleting everything before saving the new group" does come as a "feature" when working with HABTM relations, so have that in mind. Also, if you want to have this as a built-in function, why not do it yourself? Add a `saveWithDelete` or something like that to the AppModel, and create the function, in case you think this to be a regular behavior you're going to use thorough your models :)

Comment: I only use it once so no need to separate it as function. Thanks for the suggestion.